# Apex SOSL-query doesn't work

Tags: apex, sosl

Query

[image]

Result

[image]

why SOSL-query is empty?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SOSL indexing lags behind record creation, possibly by up to a few minutes. You may simply need to wait for the record to be indexed before it can be searched. You definitely *cannot* find a record that was created in the current transaction, as search indexing is asynchronous. If it's been longer than ten minutes, you should probably contact support to see if there's a problem.

Example:

```
Account a = new Account(Name='123456');
insert a;
System.debug([SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Name = '123456']); // 1 result
System.debug([FIND '123456' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Account(Name)]); // No results
```

Edit:

If you're hoping to use SOSL in a Unit Test, make sure you use [Test.setFixedSearchResults](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_SOSL.htm) in order to have your SOSL return the relevant records.

```
Account a = new Account(Name='123456');
insert a;
System.debug([SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Name = '123456']); // 1 result
Test.setFixedSearchResults(new Id[] { a.Id });
System.debug([FIND '123456' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Account(Name)]); // 1 result
```

You can't use this outside of a unit test.

Comment: Interesting. @sfdcfox